# Ansible - loop on url, username, password and generate a response file

Tags: json, loops, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a task of using ansible to loop on multiple urls, provided with each username/password, save the response json file in different filenames 'response_json_{{url}}'. 
I defined a role file as below. It works well with the single url. Where should I add the vars list? How to loop the yml file for each set of vars (url, username, password) to make sure login.set_cookie will also loop 1 by 1?
Thanks so much in advance!

```
- name: Login
  uri:
    url: https://{{url}}/rest/v1/login
    method: POST
    body: "username={{username}}&password={{password}}&action=login"
  register: login

- name: Get configuration in JSON
  uri:
    url: https://{{url}}/rest/v1/fullconfigs/running-config
    method: GET
    force: yes
    return_content: yes
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
  register: json_response

- copy:
    content: "{{json_response}}"
    dest: /home/ansible/json_response_{{url}}.json
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the variables to the `roles:` declaration, for example:

```
  roles:
    - {role: rolename, username: user1, password: pass1, filename: file1}
    - {role: rolename, username: user2, password: pass2, filename: file2}
    - {role: rolename, username: user3, password: pass3, filename: file3}
```

**NOTES:**

- i am assuming that the `url` variable is common for all roles, so you can define it in the `vars` section.
- Also, i think you could use a variable for having a unique name of file per iteration (url has invalid characters for filename anyway), i refer to the line:

`dest: /home/ansible/json_response_{{url}}.json`

you could change it to:

`dest: /home/ansible/json_response_{{filename}}.json`

**SECOND WAY:**

you can use the `include_roles` module, its similar but you will have to replace in your tasks file the `variable` with the `item.variable`. This could have implications if you had tasks with loops in the tasks file, but you dont have :) Example:

playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    accounts_variable:
      - { username: user1, password: passw1, filename: file1}
      - { username: user2, password: passw2, filename: file2}
      - { username: user3, password: passw3, filename: file3}

  tasks:
    - name: Use role in loop
      include_role:
        name: test_role
      with_items:
        - "{{ accounts_variable }}"
```

role/tasks/main.yml file:

```
---
# tasks file for test_role

- debug:
    msg: "username: {{ item.username }}, password: {{ item.password }}"
```